# scraped info to my database (using rethinkdb)

Tags: javascript, database, web-scraping, rethinkdb

I want to create a database using scraped info. How can I link the framework (totaljs) and the database (rethinkdb) with my scraped aps so when i run the scrape programs they fill the DB. I'm using totaljs as framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this is necessary to open a new process like this:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const options = {
  cwd: '/working_directory/'
};

scrappers = {
  rProperties:  () => {
    var runApi = spawn('command', ['second_argument'], options)
    runApi.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      data = JSON.parse(data)


    });
  }
}
```